# On parsing xml dates into excel (vba)

Tags: xml, excel, vba

I've got an xml file that I'd like to perform some operations on in excel. Basically, the excel file has a large number of entries called events, and inside each of those is a datetime tag. What I'd like to be able to do is simply count all the events that fall between a specific date range, but I'm new to vba and xml and stuff, and I can't quite find what I'm looking for.

Example of an xml file:

```
<event><Name>Test Event</Name><DateTime>10/09/2014 00:00:00</DateTime></Event>
<event><Name>Test Event2</Name><DateTime>10/09/2014 00:01:00</DateTime></Event>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I have done it, I use the tools in Excel.

1. Copy the XML into once cell.
2. Use Find/Replace to replace the opening tag you want to parse with a comma or other character.
3. Use Text to Columns to parse using this character.
4. Repeat these steps for the closing tag.

To sort timestamp by date, you can run Text to Columns again using " " the space between the date and time as delimiter. Then highlight the columns with dates, change the format of the column to Short Date.

If I have to count multiple instances of a tag in one XML, parsing this way will result in data across multiple columns. I use a macro to loop through all of the rows and enter into a new column for sorting/counting.